# Get nth-last-child() for a <tr> with a particular class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, user-interface

I wanted to select the 3rd last `<tr>` which has the class `record` and then add another class to it. So for example, I have a table like below:

```js
$('tr.record:nth-last-child(3)').addClass('load-next-set');
$('.record:nth-last-child(3)').addClass('load-next-set');
```

```css
.load-next-set {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
       <tr class="record">
          <td>info 1</td>
          <td>info</td>
          <td>info</td>
          <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>info 2</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>info 3</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="record">
         <td>info 4</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="record">
         <td>info 5</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="record">
         <td>info 6</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>info 7</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="record">
         <td>info 8</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
         <td>info</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The options that I have tried don't seem to be working. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is there only one grouping of `tr` elements? Or could there be multiple tables or tbodies?

Comment: @Lisa nth-last-child index starts from 0. use everyone of the options you've tried with index=4. for example: $('tr.record:nth-last-child(4)').addClass('load-next-set') nice try!

Comment: @slappy as of now, there is just a single `<tbody>`.

Comment: @Ariela Wouldn't that mean that I should go for index = 2, as 0, 1, 2 and 2nd is the 3rd last? But then, this still isn't loading the correct <tr>

Comment: I corrected my comment. I meant you have to use 4 index. it worked for me with your code. try it.

Comment: @Ariela, actually the nth-last-child indexing starts from 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child. The reason why `$('tr.record:nth-last-child(4)').addClass('load-next-set')` gives you the right row is because the third last `<tr>` with `record` is also the 4th last row. `tr.record` in this case, works the same as it would if you only had `tr`as the selection criteria. And again, if the indexing started from 0, wouldn't the third last row be index=2 and not 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a combination of class selector and the eq function.

```js
$('tr.record').eq(-3).addClass('load-next-set')
```

```css
.load-next-set {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr class="record">
            <td>info 1</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info 2</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info 3</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>info 4</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>info 5</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>info 6</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info 7</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>info 8</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only assign the class `record` to `tr` elements of one table (like in your example):

In vanilla javascript:

```
var n=3; // example
var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('record');
if(trs.length>=n){
    var tr = trs[trs.length-n];
    tr.classList.add("another_class");
}
```